# InvalidOperationException in System.ServiceModel.dll using Visual Studio 2015 with C++, GoogleTest Framework and Google Test Adapter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with the GoogleTest Framework and the Google Test Adapter to test some C++ Code. Here is my code

### main.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest-spi.h"

int main( int ac, char* av[] )
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest( &ac, av );
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}

TEST( Dummy_General, NumberComparison )
{
    EXPECT_EQ( 10.0, 10.0 );
    EXPECT_GT( 5, 2 );
    EXPECT_LT( 4, 6 );
}
```

When I run the test everything works as expected, but while debugging I get the following exception without even reaching the main function:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
> System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Additional information: The communication
> object,
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider, is
> in the Opening state.  Communication objects cannot be used for
> communication unless they are in the Opened state.

Later I also get:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
> Microsoft.PythonTools.VSInterpreters.dll

Between lots of:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF899DD1F28 in vstest.executionengine.exe:
> Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location
> 0x000000096EBFC0B0.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF899DD1F28 in
> vstest.executionengine.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at
> memory location 0x0000000000000000.
>
> Exception thrown at
> 0x00007FF899DD1F28 in vstest.executionengine.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x000000096EBFC0B0.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF899DD1F28 in vstest.executionengine.exe:
> Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location
> 0x000000096EBFC0B0.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF899DD1F28 in
> vstest.executionengine.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at
> memory location 0x0000000000000000.

I searched for this error without getting an answer. Might there be a bug in the Google Test Adapter?

Thanks

Marcel

Comment: Not sure how related this is, but I also got a similar error when working with MSTest, on a C# project (also in VS 2015); it seemed to immediately halt debugging on the test method. I re-ran the test and it worked without issue.